Score Profiles Azure AI search NOT WORKING
I have configured on my Index a default score profile to use on all of my seacrhes, I have an test index that has a field named 'source' if the filed is == to 'reviwed' I want those docs to be move up on the scoring over other doces since they are peer-review I work for a publish house. However after I save my index with the information, I always get an error:



But my index has the params defined look:
"scoringProfiles": [
    {
      "name": "pub_house",
      "functionAggregation": "sum",
      "text": {
        "weights": {
          "content": 10,
          "title": 2
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "fieldName": "source",
          "interpolation": "constant",
          "type": "tag",
          "boost": 5,
          "freshness": null,
          "magnitude": null,
          "distance": null,
          "tag": {
            "tagsParameter": "reviewed"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

Does any body know how to fix this issue is it a bug?
I tried to change the query to include the params but I still get the same error:


According to this documentation you need to give a scoringParameter  to avoid the error you are getting and in the format like below.
<parameter_name>-<value_to_boost>.
In your case it is.
"scoringParameters": ["reviewed-reviewed"]

In tagsParameter, you have to just give the parameter name not the value so change it to some parameter name like mytag and do query like below.
"scoringParameters": ["mytag-reviewed"]

Below is my parameter.

and search query.

If you observe the scoring has been boosted for the give scoring value.

Thank you Jayashank, the thing is that is not working for me look at the image I just posted

You are having 2 parameters the error says. So add one more parameter in the list. Also Check how many parameters are there.

I only have One sir with tags I only have One param that is 'reviewed' im so sorry

Ok please re check or re-create the index and try.

still not wokring :-(
